# Detecting parent and child page types with Python using Wagtail CMS

Tags: python, django-queryset, wagtail

I am setting up a Wagtail website.

There will be an Event Index page with Events as child pages.

Each event page could also have child pages, if it is part of a event series.

The main event will show the child events as a series of links on the page. The child events also need to display the parent event and also its own siblings.

In models.py I have an Event class. So far I am detecting children, siblings, parents like this:

```
@property
def childpages(self):
    event_children = Event.objects.live().descendant_of(self)
    return event_children

@property
def parentpage(self):
    event_parent = self.get_parent()
    return event_parent

@property
def siblingpages(self):
    event_siblings = Event.objects.live().sibling_of(self, inclusive=False)
    return event_siblings
```

Is there a way of finding out what the parent page type is? If it is the event index I wouldn't want to display it on the event page. I also wouldn't want the main event pages to show siblings.

I've tried various things with not_child_of(somepage) but not quite sure how to use this. What does 'somepage' reference? A class, a variable? I'm used to Javascript and pretty new to Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I'd write it:

```
@property
def parent_event(self):
    parent_page = self.get_parent()
    if parent_page.specific_class == Event:
        return parent_page.specific  # or just `return parent_page` if you don't need the extra detail from that page
    else:
        return None

@property
def sibling_events(self):
    parent_page = self.get_parent()
    if parent_page.specific_class == Event:
        return Event.objects.live().sibling_of(self, inclusive=False)
    else:
        # this is not a child event, so don't return siblings
        return Event.objects.none()
```

In Python, the standard way of checking whether an object is an instance of a given class (i.e. in Wagtail terms, whether a page is of a particular type) is `isinstance(parent_page, Event)`.

However, with Wagtail there's an extra complication - when you traverse up and down the page tree using methods like `get_parent` and `get_children`, there's no way for it to know in advance which page type it's going to get back - so, for performance reasons, it will return a "minimal" object of type `Page` which includes just the properties like `title` that are common to all pages. So, `self.get_parent().title` would work, but `self.get_parent().start_date` wouldn't. To turn that into a "real" object of the proper type, you'd access the property `specific`, which will do an extra database request behind the scenes to fill in the missing detail.

(Note that this doesn't apply when you run a query that explicitly asks for a specific type of page: with a query like `Event.objects.sibling_of(self)`, we know we'll be getting `Event` pages back, so we don't need to call `specific` on the results.)

So, `if isinstance(parent_page, Event):` wouldn't work - it'll always be false, because at that point `parent_page` is a basic `Page` object (regardless of whether the page is really an `Event` or an `EventIndex`).

`if isinstance(parent_page.specific, Event):` *would* work, but it's a little bit inefficient, because in the case that `parent_page` is the event index page, you're firing off an extra database request that you don't really need. A better alternative is to use `parent_page.specific_class`, which tells you the specific type of the page without firing off that extra database request.